# Restrict calendar selection to only one month

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using a calendar view to select the date for delivery of the product. I want to show only one full month in the calendar view from the current date?

Say for example:

Today's date: 04/04/2019 - calendar view should only show up to 31/05/2019 and shouldn't show previous month.

Another example: If today's date: 15/08/2019 - calendar view should only show up to 30/09/2019 and shouldn't show previous month.

Is this possible? if so how to show it as I see default calendar view is showing all year minus or plus whenever I click the arrows?

Answer (score -1):

**This might help you.**

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        };
```

And while calling the Calendar view.

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddReview.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            myCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);// This line adds days to MaxDate.
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(myCalendar.getTime().getTime());
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
            dialog.show();
        });
```

Now you can calculate your days by cureent date and add limit accordingly.

Comment: If I am right: It will show 30 days from the date of selection. For example, today is the 4th of April, according to your logic, calendar view will show up to 4th May. if so this won't work for me.

Comment: @SanjanaNair You need to calculate the remaining days of this month and next month and replace it with 30 that's the only thing I guess you need to do. And as per your question, I have tried my best to answer. No issues if it doesn't work for you.